# How can I get rid of 'in' in front of journal title?

Tags: biblatex

I am a Lyx user, and very new to this program (new to LaTex). I first made a reference today(using a database), and 'in' was added in front of journal titles unexpectedly. I want to erase 'in' using \DefineBibliographyExtras but don't know what kind of formatting commands. Please give me a tip.
[image]

And if anyone knows how to erase 'in' permanently, please let me know. I really hate that 'in'. I make a database with JabRef

Comment: Yay! the second method worked! Thank you so much!